# Simplify double foreach instruction

Tags: c#, ms-office

I need to browse a word document and to retrieve some Text Boxes in order to modify them.

But I need to count them before, and I do think that what I wrote is really inefficient.

I'd like to know if it's possible to simplify the following:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter OHeader in documentOld.Sections[1].Headers)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in OHeader.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.Name.Contains("Text Box"))
        {
            listTextBox.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(shape.Name.ToString(), shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.ToString()));
        }
    }
}

int count = listTextBox.Count();
```

I want to know how many elements which contain "Text Box" are in the Shapes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two ways you can do this.

Using LINQ syntax:

```
var count = (
  from OHeader in documentOld.Sections[1].Headers
  from shape in OHeader.Shapes
  where shape.Name.Contains("Text Box")).Count();
```

Or, using IEnumerable extension methods:

```
var count = documentOld.Sections[1].Headers
              .SelectMany(h => h.Shapes)
              .Count(s => s.Name.Contains("Text Box"));
```

Note that your version is inefficient in that it creates a list and the `KeyValuePair`s needlessly, given that you only want to count the number of shapes that match some condition. Other that that, nested `foreach` blocks are fine for performance, but may lack in readability versus the LINQ equivalents.

Also, please note that I have not tested the code above.

Comment: Worth noting that the code in the question uses `Contains` but the question asks for equals so `Equals` could be used

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your code the same by using the `foreach` loops still all you need to do is have your `count` variable before the loops and increment it each time you find a match.

```
int count = 0;
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter OHeader in documentOld.Sections[1].Headers)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in OHeader.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.Name.Contains("Text Box"))
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
}
```